# Jacoco Coverage and Report Task with Ant

Tags: java, ant, jacoco

Hopefully I am posted all the necessary details about this build file. Coverage task works fine and all the test cases runs.

**Jacoco.exec** is also generated but report task fails `stating Unable to read execution data file C:/path/to/file/jacoco.exec`.

Cant figure out what I am doing wrong. Any additions or alternative way ??

```
<taskdef uri="antlib:org.jacoco.ant" resource="org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml">
    <classpath path="${JACOCO.HOME}/lib/jacocoant.jar"/>
</taskdef>

<target name="runtest" depends="compile">
    <jacoco:coverage destfile="${testdest}/jacoco.exec" xmlns:jacoco="antlib:org.jacoco.ant" exclclassloader="sun.reflect.DelegatingClassLoader:javassist.Loader" >
        <junit haltonfailure="yes" fork="true" forkmode="once" printsummary="on">
            <classpath refid="project.classpath" />
            <classpath location="${testdest}" />
            <formatter type="xml"/>
            <batchtest fork="yes">
                <fileset dir="${testdest}" />
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
    </jacoco:coverage>

    <jacoco:report xmlns:jacoco="antlib:org.jacoco.ant">
        <executiondata>
            <file file="${testdest}/jacoco.exec" />
        </executiondata>

        <structure name="Jacoco">
            <classfiles>
                <fileset dir="${dest}" />
            </classfiles>
            <sourcefiles encoding="UTF-8">
                <fileset dir="${src}" />
            </sourcefiles>
        </structure>

        <html destdir="${testsrc}/report" />
    </jacoco:report>
```

Comment: please add showoutput=true for junit task.  Is there an exception stack trace?

Comment: This is what I get: [jacoco:report] Loading execution data file C:\path\to\file\test\bin\jacoco.exec

BUILD FAILED
C:\path\to\file\build.xml:58: Unable to read execution data file C:\path\to\file\test\bin\jacoco.exec

Comment: There must be large exception stack trace. Post to original question

Comment: The file is probably corrupt. What is the jacoco version? Java version... add those info to Question, please.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I figured out what was going wrong.

Comment: Please  post your  answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well above stated code works perfectly. What went wrong was, I tried to run the build file too many times due to this the existing jacoco.exec was corrupt(due to failed Junit test i think) and it was not being executed. I deleted the jacoco.exec file and ran the file again which generated new jacoco.exec file which executed perfectly.